# Play framework 2.1 application deployment

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, playframework-2.0, cloud

I've created my first Play application. Which is the most suitable deployment method for production? Should i copy the whole project to the production server and run play start? or should i make a war out of my application and deploy in tomcat / jboss? Which is the most recommended way? Getting confused with it comparing to its rails type of behavior. Note that this is supposed to be a big data application and also it may server loaded requests later on. So we are thinking of scalability, availability, performance aspects too. This application is decided to be deployed in a cloud.

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As others have stated, using the `dist` command is the easiest way to deploy Play for a one-off application.  However, to elaborate, I have here some other options and my experience with them:

- When I have an app that I update frequently, I usually install Play on the server and perform updates through Git.  Doing so, after every update, I simply run `play stop` (to stop the running server), sometimes I then run `play clean` to clear out any potentially corrupted libraries or binaries, then I run `play stage` to ensure all prerequisites are present and to perform compilation, and then finally `play start` to run the server for the updated app. It seems like a lot, but it is easy to automate via a quick bash script.
- Another method is to deploy Play behind a front-end web server such as Apache, Nginx, etc.  This is mostly useful if you want to perform some sort of load balancing, but not required as Play comes bundled with its own server.  Docs: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/HTTPServer
- Creating a WAR archive using the play2war plugin is another way to deploy, but I wouldn't recommend it unless you are giving it to someone who already has a major infrastructure built upon these servlet containers you mentioned (as many large companies do).  Using a servlet containers adds a level of complexity that Play is supposed to remove by nature (hence the integrated server).  There are no notable performance gains that I am aware of using this method over the two previously described.
- Of course, there is always the `play dist` which creates the package for you, which you upload to your server and run `play start` from there.  This is probably the easiest option. Docs: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ProductionDist

For performance and scalability, the Netty server in Play will function very adequately to exceptional for what you require. Here's a reputable link showing Netty with the fastest performance of all frameworks and a "stock" Play app as coming in somewhere in the middle of the field, but way ahead of Rails/Django in terms of performance: http://www.techempower.com/blog/2013/04/05/frameworks-round-2/.

Don't forget, you can always change your deployment architecture down the road to run behind a front-end server as described above if you need more load balancing and such for availability.  That is a trivial change with Play.  I still would not recommend the WAR deployment option unless, like I said, you already have a large installed base of servlet containers in use that someone is forcing you to serve your app with.

Scalability and performance also has a lot more to do with other factors as well, such as your use of caching, the database configuration, use of concurrency (which Play is good at) and the quality of the underlying hardware or cloud platform.  For instance, Instagram and Pinterest serve millions of people every day on a Python/Django stack which has mediocre performance by all popular benchmarks.  They mitigate that with lots of caching and high-performing databases (which is usually the bottleneck in large applications).

At the risk of making this answer too long, I'll just add one last thing. I, too, used to fret over performance and scalability, thinking I needed the most powerful stack and configuration around to run my apps.  That just isn't the case any more unless you're talking like Google or Facebook scale where every algorithm has to be finely tuned as it will be bombarded a billion times every day.  Hardware (or cloud) resources are cheap but developer/sysadmin time isn't. You should consider ease of use and maintainability for deployment of your app over raw performance comparisons, even though in the case of Play the best performing deployment configuration is arguably the easiest option as well.

Comment: Thanks, very detailed answer... :) By the way, i'm using MongoDB to go with this application.

Comment: Thanks! Also, MongoDB is great, but, as with any database, it still has its limitations in performance.  Certain types of queries take longer than would a relational database, but the sharding for scalability is so much easier. Depends on how structured/unstructured your data is. Everything is a tradeoff in technology :-)

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to use Play's console for running application, it consumes some resources and it's main goal is fast launch while development stage.

The best option is using [`dist` command](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ProductionDist) as described in the doc. Thanks to this, you don't even need to install Play on the target machine, as `dist` creates ready to use stand-alone application containing all required elements (also build-in server, so you don't need to deploy it with WAR in any container).

If you planning to use a cloud you should also check offers ie. from Heroku, or CloudBees, which allows you to deploy your application just by... pushing changes via git repository, which is very comfortable way, check the [documentation's home](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/Home), scroll down to links: *Deploying to...* for more details.